# Showing a meromorphic function is rational

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $g$ be meromorphic on a region $R$ of $\mathbb{C}$, where $R$ is all but finitely many points of $\mathbb{C}$---that is, $R$ = $\mathbb{C}\setminus S$ for some finite set $S$. Suppose $\lim_{z \rightarrow s} |g(z)| = \infty$ for all $s \in S$ and $g$ takes infinity to infinity. Then, somehow $g$ is rational.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $g$ must take the following form:

$$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{(z-s_1)^{o_1} (z-s_2)^{o_2} \ldots (z - s_n)^{o_n} }$$

Where $S = \{ s_1, \ldots , s_n \}$ and $o_i \in \mathbb{N}$ is the order of each pole. This function clearly satisfies

$$ \lim_{z \to s_i} |g(z) | = \infty $$

if $f(z)$ doesn't kill off the poles. Now we need to satisfy

$$ \lim_{|z| \to \infty} g(z) = \infty $$

Since $f(z)$ is holomorphic [ $g(z)$ is holomorphic away from poles ], what does this allow to deduce about $f(z)$?

Hint: We need $|f(z)| > |(z-s_1)(z -s_2) \ldots (z-s_n)|$ for large enough $|z|$, what does this imply?

Comment: This is probably a dumb question. Why are the elements of $S$ necessarily poles? (Could they be essential singularities?) Also, could $g$ have more poles not contained in $S$?

Comment: Meromorphic functions can't have essential singularities. It's part of the definition.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function

Comment: Let $f(z) = e^{1/z}$. Then $f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ (it even says this in the Wikipedia article), but $z = 0$ is an essential singularity. So, a meromorphic function with the domain of the problem statement can have an essential singularity.

Comment: @PaulHurst, perhaps you mean that meromorphic functions cannot have essential singularities in their domains?

Comment: If we have an essential singularity, it would be impossible to have the condition that $g(z)\to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$. Also, I assumed all the poles were simple, I'll make an edit to adjust that they may not be (it really doesn't matter, it's just a bigger polynomial). Last thing, if $g$ had more poles we can make the same argument as long as there are finitely many...but I don't think the question means that.